# Issue in Resumable Upload on Google Drive

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, resume-upload

I am trying to upload large file on Google drive performing Resumable upload.

Here is the code flow

> Step 1 : Creating file on Google Drive using Drive service and initiating the resumable upload session
>   using put request

```
    String fileID = _DriveService.Files.Insert(googleFileBody).Execute().Id;

    //Initiating resumable upload session

    String UploadUrl = null;

    String _putUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files/" + fileID  + "?uploadType=resumable";  

    HttpWebRequest httpRequest =  (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_putUrl);    
    httpRequest.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + AccessToken;
    httpRequest.Method = "PUT";
    requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream();
    _webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();

    if (_webResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
     {
         //Getting response OK
           UploadUrl = _webResponse.Headers["Location"].ToString();          
     }
```

> Step 2 : Uploading chunks to using UploadUrl . The byte array is in multiple of 256kb and call to this function is in the loop for every chunk

```
    private void AppendFileData(byte[] chunk)
    {
      try
        {
          HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(UploadUrl);
          httpRequest.ContentLength = chunk.Length;
          httpRequest.Headers["Content-Range"] = "bytes " + startOffset + "-" + endOffset+ "/" + sourceFileSize;
          httpRequest.ContentType= MimeType;
          httpRequest.Method = "PUT";

         MemoryStream stream =new MemoryStream(chunk);

          using (System.IO.Stream requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream())
                    {
                        stream.CopyTo(requestStream);
                        requestStream.Flush();
                        requestStream.Close();
                    }

          HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)(httpRequest.GetResponse()); // Throws exception as 
          //System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (308) Resume Incomplete.
         //at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
         // There is no data getting appended to file
        // Still executing the append for remaining chunks

        }
      catch(System.Net.WebException ex)
        {
        }
    }
```

For my last chunk which is not multiple of 256KB I am getting error as

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400)
>   Bad Request.    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

What I am doing wrong in this code? Please suggest.
Thanks in advance

Mayuresh.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if the last chunk is passing the correct size and not the entire array as stated in this [forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-documents-list-api/n3eHqpxl_xY). Ali has stated in that forum that "one potential issue is this: if you are sending a byte array which is half empty for the last request (i.e. the buffer has been read in less than the chunk size)." Here is a sample implementation of [resumable upload](https://gist.github.com/lamwaihen/968f577baea6eef0c123c4a83c263d67). Hope this helps.

Comment: I figured it out. Issue was due to "Content-Range". The endoffset for last request should be less than one by total file size